# X-mean algorithm BIC calculation question

Tags: k-means, bic

I'm having trouble understanding some of the formulas in [this](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dpelleg/download/xmeans.pdf) paper related to BIC calculation (Dan Pelleg and Andrew Moore, *X-means: Extending K-means with Efficient Estimation of the Number of Clusters*).

First the variance equation:

- R - number of points
- K - number of clusters
- $\mu_i$ - centroid associated with ith point.
- $\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{R-K}\sum_{i}(x_i - \mu_{(i)})^2 $

The log likelyhood then uses this sigma.
Am I reading this right, they're using 1 covariance matrix for all clusters (see quote below, they are)?  This makes no sense.  If you have 5 clusters, each one is a Gaussian according to k-means algorithm.  So wouldn't it make sense to compute covariance $\sigma^2_i$ for each cluster and use that?

My second question is regarding number of parameters to use in the BIC score.  The paper mentions

> Number of free parameters $p_j$ is simply the sum of K-1 class
>   probabilities, M*K centroid coordinates, and one variance estimate.

How do you get the K-1 class probabilities?  I could do # of points in class i / total number of points.  But then it's K-1, which probability is left out of the sum?

P.S.  If anyone has a nicer paper on estimating k using similar methods I'd like to read that as well.  At this point I'm not too concerned with speed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your first question will be answered if you go back and transcribe the variance formula correctly and then refer to the definition of $\mu_{(i)}$ at the end of section 2.  The second question is hard to understand: $p_j$ is a *count* equal to $K-1 + M*K + 1$.  There's nothing left to estimate!

Comment: First question, still don't get it.  My mistake was subscript $x_i$?  Second question.  Thank you, that was my reading comprehension.  I thought it was sum of probabilities ....  Instead as you point out it's sum of K-1 and other terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the clusters be indexed by $j = 1, \ldots, K$ with $K_j \gt 0$ points in cluster $j$.  Let $\mu_j$ (*no* parentheses around the subscript) designate the mean of cluster $j$.  Then, because by definition $\mu_{(i)}$ is the mean of whichever cluster $x_i$ belongs to, we can group the terms in the summation by cluster:

$$\eqalign{
\sigma^2 &= \frac{1}{R-K}\sum_{i}(x_i - \mu_{(i)})^2 \\
         &= \frac{1}{R-K}\sum_{j=1}^K\sum_{k=1}^{K_j}(x_k - \mu_j)^2 \\
         &= \frac{1}{R-K}\sum_{j=1}^K K_j \frac{1}{K_j}\sum_{k=1}^{K_j}(x_k - \mu_j)^2 \\
         &= \frac{1}{R-K}\sum_{j=1}^K K_j \sigma_j^2
},$$

with $\sigma_j^2$ being the variance within cluster $j$ (where we *must* use $K_j$ instead of $K_j-1$ in the denominators to handle singleton clusters). I believe this is what you were expecting.

Comment: Thanks, no this is not what I was expecting at all.  I was expecting to compute covariance matrix for each j - dimension M > 1.  Use $\mu_j$ along with covariance j, in its own multi variate Gaussian distribution to compute point probability.  And since the means add M*K free parameters.  All the covariance matrices would add M*M*K more parameters.

Comment: @Budric Well, that's not what they are doing!  Obviously they are assuming a common covariance structure around each center.  This proves your original interpretation is correct.  But why does a common covariance "make no sense"?  It's a good place to start.  You can do *post hoc* tests to see whether it's a reasonable assumption.  If it's not, then it sounds like you might need to generalize the X-means approach yourself :-).