# X-Means Calculation of BIC

Tags: k-means, bic

I am trying to calculate the BIC for the X-Means algorithm as described in the paper by Pelleg and Moore (https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dpelleg/download/xmeans.pdf).

The paper describes the calculation of the pj variable, which I do not understand completely:

The number of free parameters pj is simply the sum of K-1 class probabilities, M*K centroid coordinates, and one variance estimate.

On another post ([X-mean algorithm BIC calculation question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13103/x-mean-algorithm-bic-calculation-question)), a user described the calculated of pj as simply K-1 + M*K + 1. I am wondering if anyone has any knowledge as to whether this is correct or not?

Answer (score 1):

The two sources you cite give the same answer: 
$p_j$ is the number of free parameters in a model with $K$ clusters:

- $K-1$ cluster probabilities (the $K^{th}$ being forced because they sum to $1$)
- $MK$ centroid coordinates ($K$ centroid, each with $M$ features)
- $1$ variance estimate, assuming common covariance (per answer to the linked question)